# If Condition inside a With Statement

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code , I filter on "PENDING: first and then filter columns 10 and 2 on "USA" respectively.
all the filtered data is copied.
But now I want to filter on "CANADA" and "USA", but want to only copy if the 
cell in Column 10 = "USA" and cell in Column 2 = "USA"
                     OR
cell in Column 10 = "CANADA" and cell in Column 2 = "CANADA"
I know how to filter on both "USA" and "CANADA". I want to know where to add the If condition in the code.

```
ub SS()

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim LastCol As String




    ' Define workbooks paths
    sourceWorkbookPath = "Path 1"
    targetWorkbookPath = "Path 2"

    ' Set a reference to the target Workbook and sheets
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' definr worksheet's names for each workbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("WEXOS")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")



    With sourceSheet


        Row = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Find the empty column after the last column
        lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

        '~~> Get the column Name
        LastCol = Split(Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1)

        '~~> Insert the formula
        .Range(LastCol & "2:" & LastCol & lRow).Formula = "=IF(N2=""PENDING"",IF(OR(B2&J2=""USAUSA"",B2&J2=""CANADACANADA""),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)"

        '~~> Remove existing filter
        .AutoFilterMode = False


        ' Get last row
         lastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("A1:" & LastCol & lRow)

          .AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:="=TRUE"

        '.Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        '.Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="USA", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="CANADA"
        '.Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="USA", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="CANADA"

    End With

        .Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("G2")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A2")
        .Range("E2:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B2")
        .Range("G2:G" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("C2")
        .Range("I2:I" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F2")
        .Columns(lCol).Delete


    End With

    'Rest of the Code


    On Error Resume Next
    sourceSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Criteria1:="=Canada", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=USA"` for both columns

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout . yes...I know that...I mentioned that in the question. I'm asking for help on the If condition after this filter.

Comment: I am sorry. I am confused. IF condition for what?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout . Apologies for the confusion. After the filter for USA or CANADA there would be 4 possibilities in the rows 1. US TO US 2. CANADA TO CANADA 3. USA TO CANADA 4. CANADA TO USA.......But I just want to copy the data for USA TO USA AND CANADA TO CANADA

Comment: Easiest would be to add a helper column before you filter. It will be much more easier. For example in Col R put this formula "=B2=J2" and after the above filter do a final filter on col R for `True`

Comment: You can dynamically also put this formula in the last column and then delete the last column at the end of the code

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout I don't want to use Column R...can't I use an IF AND condition?

Comment: You can but then you will have to loop though the visible range after filter and match the columns and hide the row which fail the IF condition. Easiest would be to  use the last column. I can help you with a quick code on how to use the last column

Comment: @SiddharthRout okay...what if someone uses the last column for something else...this file is used by many people...but lets try out

Comment: Hi @RicardoDiaz

Comment: I am not using the last column. I am using the empty column after the last column ;)

Comment: Try the code that I posted

Comment: YOu can also use the formula `=IF(N2="Pending",IF(OR(B2&J2="USAUSA",B2&J2="CANADACANADA"),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)` int he below code and then filter only on this column. No need for the extra autofilters

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim LastCol As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in col J
        lRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Find the empty column after the last column
        lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

        '~~> Get the column Name
        LastCol = Split(Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1)

        '~~> Insert the formula
        .Range(LastCol & "2:" & LastCol & lRow).Formula = "=B2=J2"

        '~~> Remove existing filter
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Work with the relevant range
        With .Range("A1:" & LastCol & lRow)
           .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=PENDING"
           .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="=Canada", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=USA"
           .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Canada", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=USA"
           .AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:="=TRUE"
        End With

        '
        '~~> Rest of your copy code
        '

        '~~> In the end delete the column after you finished copying
        .Columns(lCol).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Its giving me error for the below.                                                                     
.Range(LastCol & "2:" & LastCol & lRow).Formula = "=IF(N2="PENDING",IF(OR(B2&J2="USAUSA",B2&J2="CANADACANADA"),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)"

Comment: You have to pad the double quotes. `.Range(LastCol & "2:" & LastCol & lRow).Formula = "=IF(N2=""PENDING"",IF(OR(B2&J2=""USAUSA"",B2&J2=""CANADACANADA""),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)"`

Comment: Okay that fixed it...but now it is giving the error as Method Range of Object failed

Comment: Can you share the exact code that you are using? All you hade to do in my code was to insert your copy code in `'~~> Rest of your copy code` :) The above code is tried and tested...

Comment: Hi Siddharth....I edited my own code so that you can see my whole code.

Comment: If you are using the formula then you need only one filter code `.AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:="=TRUE"` Delete the others. Also if you are using `With .Range("A1:" & LastCol & lRow)` then you do  nto need to specify the range again inside like you did

Comment: Hi Siddharth.....I changed that...it is still giving me Run-Time error 1004...method Range of Object Failed in the line which has the formula

Comment: The line having the formula

Comment: Just tested the formula and it works. debug th eline and check what is the value of  `lCol`, `LastCol` and `lRow`

Comment: Its still giving me error in that line....I used F8 to debug line by line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210759/discussion-between-roy-and-siddharth-rout).